# Sequelize: How to do a COUNT for a 3rd level included model

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 3 entities: `Lead`, `Company`, and `Project`. Lead belongs to many Companies, and Companies has many Projects.

I managed to get the Projects showing using this:

```
    Lead.findOne({
            where: { userId: req.user.id },
            include: [
                {
                    model: Company,
                    as: 'assignedTo',
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: Project,
                            attributes: ['id'],
                            as: 'children'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]            
        })
```

What I wanted to do is COUNT the `Project`s instead of returning them.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you want to find the number of `Project`'s lead by a particular `Lead`.

If so try this way.

```
Entity3.count({ // Project model.
    include: [
    {
        model: Entity2, // Company model
        as: // DEPENDS how you manage association
        include: [
        {
            model: Entity1, // Lead Model
            as: // Depends how you manage association
            where: {
                 id: YOUR_LEAD_ID
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Hi Raful! Sorry for the seemingly cryptic question. I edited my question to properly convey what my relationships are.